# How to set English as the default input method?

Tags: input-method, environment, localization

For some reason I cannot set english, only british as the input method.

I am writing a function to switch language from spanish-postfix to english, but english is not working, only british.

I have tried `(set-input-method nil)` instead `(set-input-method english)` but it doesn't work. Only `(set-input-method british)` works but the `#` is replaced with `£` and you have to press it two times to get `#`: that's not good at all.

Any advice how to be able to switch to default US keyboard?
Because nil is not working when jumping from spanish or other language to nil.

Comment: The documentation of `set-input-method` says that `(set-input-method nil)` should work. What is the value of `current-input-method` after you do that? And how exactly does it not work?

Comment: BTW, if you say `M-x describe-input-method RET TAB` you will get all the  possible completions. You will see that there is a `british` input method but no `english` input method.

Comment: It isn't working. When I am on Spanish or Esperanto or Greek keyboard input and press my keybinding that runs function that has (set-input-method nil) in it nothing happens. But when I replace nil in the same function with e.g. british or esperanto-postfix etc., it works) So the problem is the nil and nothing else. I have tried it with many combinations and the nil value is the problem. Try it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: I do `ESC-ESC : (set-input-method 'greek)`, I can type greek letters into the buffer and the value of `current-input-method` is `"greek"`. I then do `ESC-ESC : (set-input-method nil)` and I can type the normal characters associated with my US keyboard (including `#` and `$`) and the value of `current-input-method` is `nil`. Are you sure that your keybinding is correct?